# Add a custom block after category products price section in magento2

Tags: magento2, product, category

I would like to add a custom block in category landing page, after the product price section,

Iam using the below code but it is adding after the add to cart but i wants to add after price section,

```
  <referenceContainer name="category.product.addto.compare">
    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="Vendor_Module::category/banner_category.phtml" name="banner_category_ptk" after="category.products.list"/>
```

Please help me how to do this, what is proper container name i have to use in magento2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think using layout you will easily add this block after price section.I guess that you are trying to add this block to every product

and, using [`Plugin`](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html) on the method  `getProductPrice()` and add a block after Price section on listing section.

So.  create **Around plugin on the function** `getProductPrice()` and your block output HTML to this function.

The `di.xml` file in your module declares a plugin for a class object:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\AbstractProduct">
      <plugin name="add_custom_block" type="My\Module\Plugin\AddCustomBlock" sortOrder="1" disabled="false" />
    </type>
</config>
```

**Plugin Class:**

```
<?php

namespace My\Module\Plugin;


class AddCustomBlock
{
    public function afterGetProductPrice(
        \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\AbstractProduct $subject,
        $output,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product
    )
    {
        $customBlockHtml = '';
        $name = 'banner_category_ptk_' . $product->getId();
        $customBlock = $subject->getLayout()->getBlock($name);
        if (!$subject->getLayout()->getBlock($name)) {
            $customBlock = $subject->getLayout()->createBlock(
                \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template::class,
                $name,
                ['product' => $product]
            );
        }


        if ($customBlock) {
            $customBlock->setTemplate('Vendor_Module::category/banner_category.phtml');
            $customBlockHtml = $customBlock->toHtml();
        }

        return $output . $customBlockHtml;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Amit Thanks for your answer, i would like to add a custom div using banner_category.phtml so that i will written all my functoinality in that phtml file only.

Comment: That div should add after the price section.

Comment: @shivashankarm  try with this ======= return $customBlockHtml;

Comment: works fine  what i m expect

Comment: tested this solution and it gives error " Invalid expression in /home/faitatzis/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Config/Dom.php on line 336"

Comment: Answer is updated. here i use afterplugin

Comment: @AmitBera This solution works, but as soon as I click on the product, it gives an error "n element with a "stock_status_328" ID already exists."

Comment: i will update the answer

Comment: The answer is updated. Now the issue has been resolved.